# Adding views in Express/ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Basic question time:

I'm new to node.js/express/ejs.

How do I add a new ejs powered page to my server?

Example: I want to have a new page on my server that shows up as mysite.com/foo.html, and I want it to be rendered through app.router & ejs. How do I add this page and start to edit it?

I've started by working from the example of index.*js* that comes with the default express --ejs install. But digging into that code, 'find ./ -name "index.*js*"' comes up with no less than 25 different files that might be involved in producing that two-line index page.

Start me on the right path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `views` directory add a file named `foo.ejs` and add the EJS you want to be rendered.

Then create another file named `foo.js` in the `routes` directory. Here is what the content

```
module.exports.index = function(req, res){ 
  res.index('foo');
};
```

In the main express app file (the one you run via `node app.js`) first require the new route

```
var foo = require('./routes/foo');
```

then tell express about it

```
app.get('/foo.html', foo.index);
```

Comment: You're right. Fixed the `require`. For the second error, in `foo.js` it try change `exports.index` to be `module.exports.index`